# Can I use Odin 3.12.7 T Flash option to install u-boot onto my SD card without tripping knox?

Tags: samsung, external-sd, bootloader, odin, samsung-galaxy-tab

I'm curious, if I can eventually dual boot on my Galaxy Tab Active 3, because some games are broken on the newest One UI and I want to take control over my OS without the limiting security and guarantee risks, disabling the ability to update for example.

However this question only focusses on the custom bootloader U-boot for the SD card.

Has anyone an idea if this will work, because it would be a huge step forward for the Samsung Android community?

Any answer is appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [booting Android from SD card](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/134210/booting-android-from-sd-card)

Comment: No, since in step 3 you have to modify files in the kernel to boot from sd card instead of internal memory, which probably trips Knox, but since -t option is there, I wonder if it's able to boot from SD by default.

Comment: I accept answers to boot U-boot as secondary bootloader as well.

Comment: To my knowledge there is not a single Google Android phone that is able to boot from sd-card without any system modifications.

Comment: That's another thread I created, this one is specific about Samsung phones. In that thread it was not about SD but booting from ramdisk and then from SD, but else, why would the T Flash option be there?

Comment: Sorry but sounds like a myth, every post i found about [T flash](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/196304/what-does-odins-t-flash-option-do) is talking about [GT-I9300](https://www.xda-developers.com/fix-your-soft-bricked-galaxy-s-iii-samsungs-way). Anyway to me it looks more like some read back option than external boot option, all it does is dump the bootloader off working device

Comment: Too bad, it only flashes from SD, can you please post it as an answer?